# Get what table row a checkbox points to in Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am trying to build an app where I have a dynamically built table with row entries.

The problem is that I need to know what row, specifically what row index, is being checked. I have some private members of the class that hold Strings that I populate for the table.

But this returns the last entry every time. This is because the entry that was update last is still kept and the ones before it are all overriden. However, I am not sure how I can get the entry that a particular checkbox is checked off on.
How can I accomplish this, and if possible, is there an easier way? The reason I have set up as below is because I receive a list (converted from a json) of some objects that I am using to populate this table. However, this list may vary in size each time so I have not predefined a table. I am really confused on how I can have Java behave as I'd like.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);
    eventsResponse = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.getExtras();
    eventsResponse = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("event_response");

    table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.events_table);

    for (int i = 0; i < eventsResponse.size(); i+=3) {
        View view = new View(this);
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        id = new TextView(this);
        type = new TextView(this);
        date = new TextView(this);
        clear = new CheckBox(this);
        id.setText("ID: " + eventsResponse.get(i));
        type.setText("Type: " + eventsResponse.get(i+1));
        date.setText("Date: " + eventsResponse.get(i+2));
        clear.setText("Clear Event");
        table.addView(id);
        table.addView(type);
        table.addView(date);
        table.addView(clear);
        table.addView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,2));

        clear.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(EventsActivity.this, "Text is: " + type.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: And I've also tried to take this listener out of the for loop, but then it displays nothing. Not sure if taking it out is even the right solution...

Comment: at the end of a single loop how many rows do you have or get? do you know `ListView` ?

Comment: @Elltz I get the size of the list I need. It's just that the view is updated each time and since on the nth update it stores the last String, the checkbox always points to the last entry. I have used ListView, but ListView does not have rows/columns that a TableView provides

Answer (score 0):

Your eventsResponse is probably returning only one entry. Use a breakpoint to check the size of eventsResponse to know how many entries to expect.

Comment: No the response is returning the appropriate size else my table wouldn't be getting populated on the UI and I've printed out the entries. The problem is since it's doing it in a loop, I do not have a way to track which checkbox corresponds to a particular entry...

Answer (score 0):

I use the setTag method to store the position of the checkbox the first time i create it.

```
 clear.setTag(i /*your row number*/);
```

to retrieve, i use

```
  clear.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
            {
                int row = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                //... the rest of your codes
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I was trying to do this but the listener is not getting any on clicks outside of the loop, which I am confused about why that is. And do you mean setId() or setTag()?

Comment: your problem is probably because you used the wrong listener. try "SetOnClickListener". see http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/